# Querying an API with form using GET (PHP:Curl, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, curl

So question.. Bear with me (I'm just learning)! :)

I have two files (index.php / form_get.php)

The index.php file, has a form that stores a variable on user submission that the form_get.php file then uses in the URL to request the json file. But when I submit the two letter country code in the form, i'm not getting the result below the form as I thought I would be with the javascript.

live form: <www.caseytetens.com/gettest/index.php>

**index.php**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Covid Country</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      function submit_soap(){
        var cc=$("#covid_country").val();
        $.get("form_get.php",{cc:cc},
        function(data){
          $("#json_response").html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
  <center>
    <h3>Get Covid Country Travel Data</h3>
     <form>
     Country Code: <input name="covid_country" id="covid_country" type="text" /><br />
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit_soap()"/>
    </form>
       <br>-----------
      <div id="json_response"></div>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**form_get.php**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.traveladviceapi.com/search/".$cc.,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Access-Token:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 thinks I notice in your code.

1. `CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.traveladviceapi.com/search/".$cc.,` you have a dot at the end of your variable.
2. you have to initialize the `$cc` variable `$cc = $_GET['cc'];`

Answer (score 0):

In the `form_get.php` file, You didn't retrieve the data that you passed in the `index.php` file. You need to add `$_GET['cc']` to the top of your `form_get.php` file to retrieve the 'cc' value.

```
<?php
$cc = $_GET['cc'];

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.traveladviceapi.com/search/".$cc,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "X-Access-Token:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Great :) Please accept one of the answers if that helped you.